# Why JMM produces (0, 0) even though it is considered a forbidden result

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

I am checking some statements from JMM and I wrote a JCS test like this:

```
@JCStressTest
@State
@Outcome(expect = ACCEPTABLE,  desc = "ACCEPTABLE")
public class ConcurrencyTest {
    private final int a = 1;
    private final int b = 2;

    public ConcurrencyTest instance;
    
    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
        instance = new ConcurrencyTest();
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2(II_Result result) {
        ConcurrencyTest c = instance;
        if (c != null) {
            result.r1 = c.a;
            result.r2 = c.b;
        }
    }
}
```

After running this test, I see the following results:

> (0, 0) (1, 2)

Although the JMM explicitly states that the result (0, 0) is forbidden, why is this happening?

Comment: Why so? `c` reads `null`, both `r1` and `r2` remain zero.

Comment: @AndrewVershinin, Would it be that JCS outputs the result var state even if it hasn't been updated?

Comment: @Ilya Not familiar with it, but would presume yes.

Comment: @Ilya As the previous commenter I am not familiar with JCStress, but from what I've read right now, it tries to interleave actors (threads) in different ways in order to obtain all possible execution results. In the case `actor1` completes before `actor2` reads `instance`, the `(0, 0)` result is achieved.

Comment: Thank you, this is really the only reasonable behavior in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's change the code a little bit to begin with:

```
@JCStressTest
@State
@Outcome(id = "0, 0", expect = Expect.FORBIDDEN)
@Outcome(id = "1, 2", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE)
@Outcome(id = "-1, -1", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE)
public class ConcurrencyTest {

    private final int a = 1;
    private final int b = 2;

    public ConcurrencyTest instance;

    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
        instance = new ConcurrencyTest();
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2(II_Result result) {
        ConcurrencyTest c = instance;
        if (c != null) {
            result.r1 = c.a;
            result.r2 = c.b;
        } else {                   // <-- this is what you care about
            result.r1 = -1;
            result.r2 = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Where do you think that the values from `@Outcome(id = "0, 0")` are coming from? These are the ones you set in `II_Result` that holds two `int`s, that have a default value of `0`.

As such, when `c == null` (meaning that `actor1` has not run), that `if (c != null) { ...`  will not be entered. So, in your code, you would do nothing : resulting in those default values of `r1` and `r2` being zero. You should take care of this default cases, via a simple `else`, like I did.